# Themed WPF ListBox-Object looks different than ListboxItem?

Tags: wpf, inheritance, listbox, themes, listboxitem

When I use a Theme like [link text](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes) in my WPF App, I notice a difference between the Items of ListBoxes and ComboBoxes: When I add a an object of my own class to their Items Collection, the created item looks themed. If I make my own class inherit from ListBoxItem/ComboBoxItem, the resulting Visualization looks unthemed.

How can I define my own ListBoxItem/ComboBoxItem that looks themed?